# Twitter Bootstrap: using submit form as drop down menu items?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Instead of using anchors or buttons in a drop down menu, I want to have a form for each item. The form contains some hidden fields and a submit button. When I put the form in each `<li>` of my mark up, the UI was messed up. Does Bootstrap support this natively? If not, I'm going to re-code my application to work with links.

**Update 1: screen shot**

[image]

**Update 2: mark up**

```
  <div class="btn-group open">
    <button class="btn">Action</button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <form action="#" method="post">
          <fieldset>
            <input type="submit" value="Favorite"/>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </li>

      <li><a href="#">Message</a></li>

      <li>
        <form action="#" method="post">
          <fieldset>
            <input type="submit" value="Smile"/>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </li>

      <li>
        <form action="#" method="post">
          <fieldset>
            <input type="submit" value="Block"/>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </li>

      <li>
        <form action="#" method="post">
          <fieldset>
            <input type="submit" value="Friend"/>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </li>

      <li>
        <form action="#" method="post">
          <fieldset>
            <input type="submit" value="Exclude From Future Search Results"/>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Update 3: icons

I want the submit buttons to have an icon. Not sure what's the best way to do that, but this is my solution:

```
<label for="foo">
   <i class="icon-ok></i> Favorite
</label>
<input id="foo" style="display:none;" type="submit" value="Favorite"/>
```

The submit form is hidden, the label is shown with icon, and when user clicks on the label, it works. No JS required.

Comment: Can you show us what it looked like after `<form>` code was added to the drop down menu?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if I understand what you mean about the submit form being hidden but the label showing an icon however I was able to override the buttons with an image.  Please see the attached jsBin.  I did it by adding a class to the input's

http://jsbin.com/eboqij/1/edit

```
.button{
background-image:url('http://www.nyanicorn.com/res/img/icon_nyan.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
text-indent:-9999px;
  width:40px!important;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just use Javascript to store the value in a hidden field and submit the form -- you're probably using JS anyways handle the open/close of the dropdown.

I had the exact same problem and I've created this new "submit" plug-in:

```
!function ($) {
  "use strict"; // jshint ;_;

  $(document).on('click.submit.data-api', '[data-submit]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    var form= $('#'+$(this).data('submit'))

    form.find('input[name="'+$(this).data('name')+'"]').val($(this).data('value'))

    form.submit()
  })

}(window.jQuery);
```

Which I can use thus:

```
<form id="myform" ...>
  <input type="hidden" name="myparam">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
      Action
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <a data-submit="myform" data-name="myfield" data-value="myvalue>
          Click here
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```